# Nodal Analysis ..Nodes between Battery and Resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I have the following circuit for which Nodal Analysis is performed

At this point

[image]

Isn't there a Node between the resistor and the battery? 
How can i propery identify Nodes in this circuit?

UPDATE:
Please see the update

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

UPDATE#3

[image]

Comment: Is there a distinct voltage there? Then it's a node!

Comment: @Daniel I'm referring this page-Example 2 .So is there a node there..are they right? http://www.calvin.edu/~svleest/circuitExamples/NodeVoltageMeshCurrent/

Comment: Removed Image #2 as i cannot post more than 2 links..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@elecman, yes there is a node between the resistor and the battery. There are 4 nodes in that circuit. You've detected one which is between the 10 ohm resistor and the 4v battery. The ground can be considered as a node as well. I'll let you identify the other 2 nodes. Do you know how to get the Nodal Analysis Equations for this circuit?

Comment: Thanks..But if there is a node between the resistor and battery there will be more than 4 nodes in the circuit right? Yeah,i know to get the Nodal Equations using KCL.

Comment: @elecman, no because most of other nodes that you are seeing are really the same node just at different points. Where do you see two or more elements coming together at? 1st node is where the 10 ohm resistor and 4v battery come together at. 2nd node is where 5amp current, 5 ohm resistor and 2 10 ohm resistors come together at. 3rd node is where 4v battery, 10 ohm resistor, 2 ohm resistor and 2amp current come together and 4th node is where 5amp current, 5 ohm resistor, 2 ohm resistor and 2amp current come together at.

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: Yeah but the two nodes at the bottom (like i said in my previous comment) are the same node just at different point. It's the same ground. Those two nodes are both ground. So the whole ground area is one node altogether.

Comment: okay.. great :) thanks for your help:) I have marked your answer as correct.I cannot upvote since i need min 15 rep to do that.

Comment: @elecman, Im not concerned about the upvote, do you know how to identify a node accurately now? Will you like to try another circuit?

Comment: Yes.. i definitely know to identify nodes now.I will try with other circuits and get back if there is an issue.Hope you will help me :)

Comment: @elecman, you are welcome. Just please have a Good Friday & A Great Weekend.

Comment: I have another doubt.Here http://www.calvin.edu/~svleest/circuitExamples/NodeVoltageMeshCurrent/soln2.nv.htm they are getting this equation `-5A + V1/5 + (V1-V2)/10 + [V1-(V2+4)]/10 = 0` at node `V1` .. Why do they take 5A as negative? KCL States that the algebraic sum of the current leaving or entering a junction should be zero.So cant i use directions as in my update #3.I simply followed this convention .. current flows from +ve to -ver terminal of the battery and just took the given current direction of current sources .And simply assumed some directions.Is this approach correct.

Comment: @elecman, sorry for the 6 hour wait. They take the 5amp current as negative because they are assuming that currents that enter the V1 node are NEGATIVE, while currents leaving the V1 node are POSITIVE. Like V1/5 current is going from V1 node down to ground. (V1 - V2)/10 current is going from V1 to V2. [V1-(V2+4)]/10 current is going from V1 to 4V.

Comment: @dsmith Thanks .. im elecman.. i had to open a new account as i can no longer ask questions here.I forgot the new account login details .. :) .Thanks for your help.. now i understand better.I think i can safely ignore the node between the battery and resistance this way.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia

> [In electrical engineering, node, refers to any point on a circuit where two or more circuit elements meet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28circuits%29)

So technically, yes. But practically, it's always V2+4... so most people would trivially incorporate that into their nodal equations rather than writing a separate one for it.

Comment: Thanks... but how do you get V2+4? .. I Know you are using KCL... but how you get V2+4.

Comment: Inspection: Look at V2. The node at the top is V2+4 volts BY DEFINITION. That's the way it's drawn.

Comment: okay.. but why do you sum V2 with 4 rather than V1?

Comment: You need to know the current through the top 10 Ohm resistor to add it to V1.